# Where to implement Restangular's Extend Model

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I'm currently migrating my application from $resouce to Restangular and I'm having trouble understanding where extendModel should be implemented.

Having read through the slides available [here](https://speakerdeck.com/mgonto/models-and-rest-apis-on-angularjs-with-restangular) on slide 46 it shows the following two snippets.

```
 Restangular.extendModel('cars', function(car){
    return Car.extend(car);
 });
```

```
module.factory('Car', function(Exteder){
function Car(){}

Car.prototype.chargeFuel = function(amount){

}

Car.extend = Extender.for('car')

return Car
});
```

My question is where should the extendModel function actually be declared? Should it be in the App.config or in a controller somewhere? I've been through the documentation several times now and I can't seem to find a concrete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much searching I believe I've found the correct place to implement this as being in the app.config section of the angular application.

Simply pass the RestangularProvider as a parameter and use `RestangularProvider.extendModel()`